# 7 - HTTP error 400 when calling system_retrieve_file()?

Tags: hooks, feeds, importing-exporting, files

I'm using `hook_feeds_after_save` and the `simpleHTMLdom` library to migrate inline images for a feed import. After I detect that an image tag exists and the url is qualified/valid I build a stream wrapper for the image file and call `system_retrieve_file`.

```
  $dirPrefix = 'archive';
  $uri = file_build_uri($dirPrefix . '/' . $filepath);

  if (file_prepare_directory($uri, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY)) {
    $destination = $uri . '/' . $filename;
    system_retrieve_file($img_url, $destination, TRUE, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
  }
```

However, I receive 400 errors on each image;
`HTTP error 400 occurred when trying to fetch http://DOMAIN.COM/C8B195/assets/images/01 Grapes 3.jpg.`

If I just plop this url into a browser I get a 200 and the image is displayed. Same when I test this in something like the Advanced Rest Client application.

Also, I'm developing this site in a local environment.

Anyone have any clue how to debug this or why I may be receiving a 400 response?

Comment: It's going to be trial & error really - first check that you can download resources from other domains ok via `drupal_http_request`, if yes then you can be reasonably sure the server giving a 400 is objecting to something in the request headers and it's not a PHP/local config issue. Do you own the remote server? If so check its config/process for anything suspicious. If not, you'll probably have to experiment with matching the headers that your browser or other client sends. Some people have a whitelist of user agent strings, for example. If that's the case you can just pretend you're Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I needed to encode urls, but not how you may expect with PHP's `urlencode` or `rawurlencode`.
For example, I needed to convert `http://DOMAIN.COM/C8B195/assets/images/01 Grapes 3.jpg` to `http://DOMAIN.COM/C8B195/assets/images/01%20Grapes%203.jpg`. I'm not sure why `system_retrieve_file` or `drupal_http_request` had a problem with the spaces.

```
  $encodedPath = rawurlencode($path);
  $encodedPath = str_replace('%3A', ':', str_replace('%2F', '/', $encodedPath));
```